# How to modify the Shiny default CSS to change the background color of the sidebarPanel?

Tags: css, r, shiny

I have a Shiny application based on a customized version of the defaullt CSS ([github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/master/inst/www/shared/shiny.css](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/master/inst/www/shared/shiny.css)). My goal is to change the background color of the `sidebarPanel` **inside this CSS**. Hence, I do not want to insert HTML in the `ui.r`. In the above CSS there is this block:

```
.shiny-input-panel {
  padding: 6px 8px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

I thought all I have to do is change the value of `background-color`, but this does not seem to have any effect at all.

**EDIT:** I call my custom CSS with `theme = "my_custom.css"` at the beginning of the `ui.r`. If I change other classes in `my_custom.css`, e. g. the class `shiny-notifications`, **the changes do have an effect.**

Comment: Hi Joe, did you try inspecting it in dev-tools ? Maybe another class is overriding that value or a parent / child is setting the same background as well ?

Comment: Hi Jake, my understanding of the matter is really basic. So I would not know how to figure that out in the dev tools.

Comment: Is your own custom CSS called after the shiny one ? There is no other background-color set for this item in the git link. Is there a typo in your code ? Or is your own custom CSS overriding it ?

Comment: The default CSS is not called anymore; I only call my custom one (see the edit). There is definitely no typo; all I change is the hex code behind `background-color:`. And, finally, I can rule out the thesis that my CSS does override the change.

Comment: Could it be set in JS in Shiny ?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not get this question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191735/discussion-between-joe-and-jake).

Comment: Was a solution to this ever found?

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
sidebarPanel(
  selectInput("dataset", "Choose a dataset:",
              choices = c("rock", "pressure", "cars")),
  numericInput("obs", "Observations:", 10), 
  style = "background-color: yellow;"
)
```

Comment: Thanks Stephane for your solution! However, I need a solution in the CSS.